# Optimizing the performance for user input

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, optimization, scripting

I'm developing a game and the main character's script goes a little like this:

On the Update (loops every frame) method, I call there funtions

```
void Update(){

   InputManager();  //I set the Vector3 direction vector for the player's movement, and 

   Move();          //I make the player move according to the InputManager() direction vector. 
                    //I also set a boolean for every player state (eg. isMoving, isCrouching, isSliding, isGrounded)

   SpeedManager();  //Performes a Linear Interpolation (Mathf.Lerp) between the current speed and the final speed for every input given. 
                    //This includes the direction vector as well as sprinting and sliding

   AnimationManager();  //We check the booleans and apply an animation accordingly
}
```

The script works fine, but I'm having concerns about performance since the game drops from 400FPS to 260FPS when I press an input. Also the game becomes unplayable if I select the player game object to which the script is attached to.

What's your two cents on this?

Comment: *[Premature Optimization Is the Root of All Evil](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)* are you sure *260* FPS is a problem? It might seem like a dramatic drop in frame rate but if it's only dropping to four to eight times faster frame rate than most people are wanting is it really something you need to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Unity Profiler to see where your time is being spent. That's the best way to tackle performance problems.

Comment: Thanks! Certainly will check it out, do you think having the all the behaviours for the inputs inside the input function itself will help?